# What is single $ sign in tpl function

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Having such Helm code snippet.

```
{{ if .Values.configOverrides }}
# Overrides
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.configOverrides }}
# {{ $key }}
{{ tpl $value $ }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

What is `$` sign in `{{ tpl $value $ }}`?

Comment: see the docs: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#:~:text=%7B%7B%20include%20%22toYaml%22-,%24,-value%20%7C%20indent%202  and/or  https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/

Comment: @Luuk I did it, but didn't find my case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/):

> However, there is one variable that is always global - $ - this variable will
> always point to the root context. This can be very useful when you are
> looping in a range and you need to know the chart's release name.

So the expression you show in your question...

```
{{ tpl $value $ }}
```

...is passing root context as the set of values to be used when expanding the template in `$value`.